How to Reduce Response Time for Hugging Face Model Inference Endpoint?
I'm currently using the Hugging Face mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2 model through an Inference Endpoint. The response time for generating answers is around 5 to 6 seconds, but I need it to be between 1 to 1.5 seconds.
Here are the details of my setup:
Model: mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2
Platform: Hugging Face Inference Endpoint
Current Response Time: 5 to 6 seconds
Desired Response Time: 1 to 1.5 seconds
client = InferenceClient(
    "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
    token=HF_TOKEN,
    timeout=120
    )
    
    BotLogger.instance().log(f'excute InferenceClient')
    chat_completion = client.chat_completion(
        messages=[
            system,
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": text
            }
        ],
    )
    BotLogger.instance().log(f'excute chat_completion')
    return chat_completion.choices[0].message.content

Are there any other methods or configurations I can use to reduce the response time? Any advice or best practices for optimizing the performance of Hugging Face Inference Endpoints would be greatly appreciated.
